# API Rest Python

Tags: python, rest

I'm working with `Python API Rest` between `Django` and `LogicalDOC`. I want to display list of directories inside one directory which have this parent ID : 8552450

I'm using this documentation : http://wiki.logicaldoc.com/rest/#/

So I have this command :

```
url = 'http://demoged.fr:8009/services/rest/folder/listChildren?folderId=8552450'
payload = {'folderId': 8552450}

headers = {'Accept': 'application/json'}
r = requests.get(url,  params=payload, headers=headers, auth=('***', '***'))

rbody = r.content
print rbody
```

And I get :

```
[{"id":8978437,"name":"LKJLKJ_OKJKJ_1900-09-12","parentId":8552450,"description":"","lastModified":"2017-02-06 14:45:40 +0100","type":0,"templateId":null,"templateLocked":0,"creation":"2017-02-06 14:45:40 +0100","creator":"Etat Civil","position":1,"hidden":0,"foldRef":null,"attributes":[],"storage":null,"tags":[]}]
```

Then, I just want to get `name` result :

```
LKJLKJ_OKJKJ_1900-09-12
```

So I tried 2 things :

```
print rbody["name"]
print rbody[1]
```

But it doesn't work. Have you an idea about command I've to write ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your `rbody` result it would be

```
rbody[0]['name']
```

However if `rbody` is a string, you need to first turn it into a Python object

```
>>> import json
>>> s = '''[{"id":8978437,"name":"LKJLKJ_OKJKJ_1900-09-12","parentId":8552450,"description":"","lastModified":"2017-02-06 14:45:40 +0100","type":0,"templateId":null,"templateLocked":0,"creation":"2017-02-06 14:45:40 +0100","creator":"Etat Civil","position":1,"hidden":0,"foldRef":null,"attributes":[],"storage":null,"tags":[]}]'''
>>> json.loads(s)[0]['name']
'LKJLKJ_OKJKJ_1900-09-12'
```

If you have several dictionaries in your list, you can use a list comprehension

```
names = [i['name'] for i in json.loads(rbody)]
```

Comment: Thank you. `[0]` corresponds to what exactly ?

Comment: I get this error : `Exception Value:  

string indices must be integers, not str`

Comment: @Valentin You have a `list` with a single `dict` inside. `[0]` indexes the first element of the `list`, then `['name']` indexes the `dict` element with that key.

Comment: In your printed json, that appears within a list, that's why you need to index that before accessing the `name` key of the dictionary.

Comment: Thank you it works with this line : `print json.loads(rbody)[0]['name']` Thanks to you ;) And thank you for the explanation

Comment: Note that with `requests` you can just use `response.json` instead of `json.loads(response.content)`.

Comment: Just one more question, if I have several lists and I want to get list of name from all lists, I have to replace `[0]` by `[ ]` ?

Comment: Thank you so much ! It's perfect ! I'm not familiar with this kind of things ^^

Answer (score 2):

The return value of your code is a list with one dictionary. It will work like this:

```
print rbody[0]["name"]
```

This error message means, that the value of *rbody* is of a string type. If you want to access the dictionary object, you have to decode the string type value like this:

```
import json
rbody = json.loads(rbody)
```

Enjoy!

Comment: It doesn't seem to work : `Exception Value:  

string indices must be integers, not str`

Answer (score -1):

print rbody[0][1]
I hope this help